# how can i talk between more than one reducers in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I found my this when i search my problem on **github.com** **react-redux-documentry** but i cant able to make sense.

```
const reducers = [ reducerA, reducerB, ..., reducerZ ];

let reducer = ( state = initialState, action ) => {
    return reducers.reduce( ( state, reducerFn ) => (
        reducerFn( state, action )
    ), state );
};
```

if i use this as `reducer(myinitialState,myAction);`
then it will only give reducers from reducer array, but how can i talk between these reducers ?